# Read file content in list

Tags: python, list, file

I have file like this:

```
1
2
3
4
O
5
6
7
8
```

How Can I read the numbers in list to be the output like this:
`[12345678]`

```
a=[]
with open(filename, 'r') as input:
   for line in input:       
        if 'ONE' in line:
            break
        a.append(line)
print(' '.join(a))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the newlines when you read the file. You can do this with `strip()`.

Don't break out of the loop when the line is `ONE`, that will prevent reading the rest of the file.

The test for `ONE` won't work for `TWO` or other non-numeric lines. Use `.isnumeric()`.

When you `.join()`, you should use an empty string as the delimiter, not a space.

Finally, you need to call `int()` to convert the joined string to an integer, and put it inside `[]` to get a list.

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    a = [line.strip() for line in f if line.strip().isnumeric()]
   
print([int(''.join(a))])
```

Don't use `input` as a variable name, it will replace the built-in function with that name.

Comment: Can I remove the newlines when read the file without using strip()?

Comment: You could use `f.read().splitlines()`

Comment: Thank you for your code. could you check my update code please? why I can not print any thing ?

Comment: `x.isnumeric()` will never be true because `x` ends with newline. You need to use `x.strip().isnumeric()`

Comment: Why is the new code appending `i` rather than `x[i]`. And `i += int(x[i])` means it will skip many elements of `x`. This is completely different from what the original code tries to do, and won't produce the desired result.

Comment: I'm just wanted to use another way without using splitlines() or strip()

Comment: Then use `f.read().splitlines()` like I suggested above. `splitlines()` removes the newlines, `readlines()` leaves them in.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I did.